# No main class found? Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, graphics

I was working on my class project. I tried to draw a face emoji using the graphics thing, but I typed in the class and it says FaceComponent is not found in the FaceComponent project. I was confused about how to name the class and main method.Also, if I want to add a frame, I would have to introduce another class and main method. How do I do that in one program?

```
package facecomponent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
 *
 * @author HelenPeng
*/
public class FaceComponent extends JComponent {

  public static void main(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D)g;
    Ellipse2D.Double interestingEmoji = new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,100,100);
    g2.draw(interestingEmoji);
    Ellipse2D .Double eye1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(25,25,10,10);
    Ellipse2D .Double eye2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(50,25,10,10);
    g2.draw(eye2);
    g2.draw(eye1);
    Line2D.Double mouth = new Line2D.Double(35,75,75,75)  ;
    g2.draw(mouth);
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/60dIr.png image link

Comment: The `main` method must have one argument of type `String[]`, yours one has an argument of type `Graphics`.

Answer (score 3):

In Java args contains the supplied command-line arguments as an array of String objects.

change
    `public static void main(Graphics g)`

> In the Java programming language, every application must contain a
>   main method whose signature is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: but then the graphic g variable is not found

Comment: should access it otherwise, they not from the main since there are only arguments that could later provide the console if that were the case go

Answer (score 0):

When your java program run as application JVM will first try to find main method will one of the below syntax, so try to change your syntax to one of the belo version.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { }//Prefered style

public static void main(String args[]) { }

public static void main(String... args) { }//which additionally allows callers to use varargs syntax
```

Comment: So now I changed it.But the variable g of Graphics in the line below the main method line can not be found.

Comment: you can call your main method from actual main method with your graphics object... for jcomponent program refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488112/how-do-i-put-graphics-on-a-jpanel

Answer (score 0):

Here your definition of main method is wrong. One solution is to have a main class and a drawing class. Change your `FaceComponent` class to below:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author HelenPeng
*/
public class FaceComponent extends JPanel
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D)g;
        Ellipse2D.Double interestingEmoji = new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,100,100);
        g2.draw(interestingEmoji);
        Ellipse2D .Double eye1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(25,25,10,10);
        Ellipse2D .Double eye2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(50,25,10,10);
        g2.draw(eye2);
        g2.draw(eye1);
        Line2D.Double mouth = new Line2D.Double(35,75,75,75)  ;
        g2.draw(mouth);
    }

}
```

Then create a new class called `FaceComponentTest` and paste the code below in it.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class FaceComponentTest 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        FaceComponent faceComponent = new FaceComponent();

        JFrame faceComponentFrame = new JFrame( "My Face" );
        faceComponentFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        faceComponentFrame.add( faceComponent );
        faceComponentFrame.setSize( 400, 400 );
        faceComponentFrame.setVisible( true );
    }
```

This will display the face. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Java");
    }
}
```

In above coding portion everything is good. But you may still get,, "no main class found"!! (It is because, I have deleted the built in class and created a new class named "FirstClass".)
For not getting this error at first 'debug' the class  and then 'run'

Comment: Try to remove line one (package ...).